# Question about using dictionaries other than using Counter(email_lst).most_common()

Tags: python

I have a question regarding my python programming. Before I ask a question, here is the instructions that I have to complete:

[Write a program to read through the example_messages.txt file and figure out who has sent the greatest number of mail messages.
The program looks for 'From ' lines and takes the second word of those lines as the person who sent the mail.  The program creates a Python dictionary that maps the sender's mail address to a count of the number of times they appear in the file.]

I attached a PDF file URL of the kind of program that I created. I also tried to attach the "example_messages" text file to Stack Overflow but wouldn't let me. So instead, I attached a photo instead.

[Program that I created] https://ibb.co/nm3dBYt
[Photo of example_messages.txt] https://ibb.co/qkmfrLn

I used the “Counter(email_lst).most_common()” function in my program to complete the task. This method works, but based on the assignment, I have to use the dictionary to complete the task, and I am having a difficult time coming up with any ideas when using dictionaries. The program should be no more than 10 lines of code. Does anyone have any ideas or suggestions?

Best Regards

Comment: Please make your question self-contained (not dependent on external links or images of code). It might help to read [ask]. As far as your question, why don't you first concentrate on making the dictionary and then figure out how to use it?

Comment: Your code seem to be Ok. It is 14 lines of code and four of them are blank. Remove blank lines and it will be 10 lines of code.

Comment: Could you post the source code directly instead of screencaps? This ensures that it's searchable and also understandable by visually impaired users relying on screenreaders.

Comment: I tried posting the picture directly to make it visually but didn't work. Any advice of how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can "manually" add 1 to entries in the dictionary and use the max() function at the end to get the entry with the highest count:

```
counts = dict()
with open('example_messages.txt') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        if not line.stastswith("From"): continue
        email = line.split()[1]
        counts[email] = counts.get(email,0) + 1
email,count = max(counts.items(),key=lambda ec:ec[1])
print(email,"hase themost sent emails which is",count)
```